# return count of likes and dislikes on image

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table contains `img_id` and `likes` columns.
Example:

```
 1  1
 1  1
 1  0
 2  0
 2  0
 3  1
```

so when run this queries:

```
select img_id, count(likes)
from my_table
where likes = 1
group by img_id
```

here's the result:

```
1  2
3  1
```

and whe I run:

```
select img_id, count(likes)
from my_table
where likes = 0
group by img_id
```

the result is:

```
1 1
2 2
```

my question is:

how can i return in query1 img_id 2 = 0 , I mean img_id = 2 has no likes
also in query 2 img_id = 3 has no dislikes so i need to return 3 -> 0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MySQL and SQL Server,

```
SELECT  img_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN likes = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalLikes,
        SUM(CASE WHEN likes = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalDisLikes
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY img_ID
```

or simply in MySQL,

```
SELECT  img_id,
        SUM(likes = 1) totalLikes,
        SUM(likes = 0) totalDisLikes
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY img_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*BOTH*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c49/2)